# Update parent in UINavigationController from SubView

Tags: xamarin.ios

Forgive me if this has been asked/answered already but I couldn't find it anywhere (at least no in Monotouch - vaguely answer for ObjC.  So completely new to Monotouch but I have everything completed in my application that I want with one exception.  I'm trying to update a parent of a subview.

Here is the scenario:

I have a UINavigationController with a UIView (not a table) which has a few buttons on it that directs via a PushViewController to a Subview.  I make some changes on the subview, which I would like reflected back on the parent.  I can of course add a manual refresh button if I wanted but was looking for something a little better.

I did see some things that referred to using a viewWillAppear but couldn't find any good examples.  My attempts failed pretty bad, so any suggestions would be great.

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `UINavigationController`, it has a "back" button on top. Once this is hit by the user (or if you pop to a previous view controller), the currently view controller shown will trigger `ViewWillDisappear` and `ViewDidDisappear` and the view below (the one with your buttons) will fire `ViewWillAppear` and `ViewDidAppear`. Just overload those and update your UI state in there.